# A question regarding the cone where the solution to an ODE lies inside

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

I am currently reading the Chapter 4 of the book *Ordinary Differential Equations* by Arnold. Here the book wants to prove the Existence and uniqueness of the solution to an ODE from the approach of the contraction mapping. In the following image, it wants to study the convergence of the Picard approximations within a small neighborhood of a single point. 
[image: Chapter 4 of *Ordinary Differential Equations*]
I understand the construction of the cylinder and even the further explanations how the solution can be sought inside the cone. However, I didn't understand the definition of the cone $K_0$ and how it lies inside the cylinder with only if $a'$ is sufficiently small. Namely, can anyone explain to me how the definition 
$$
K_0 = \{ t, x:|t-t_0| \leq a',\ |x-x_0| \leq C|t-t_0|\}
$$
comes naturally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want that the double cone $K_0$ lies completely inside the cylinder $C$, meaning that it only intersects the "time" sides of the cylinder, never the "space" mantle of it. This requires that $C|t-t_0|\le b$ and thus $Ca'\le b$, which is satisfied if $a'$ is sufficiently small. You could of course also directly take $a'=b/C$.

If you want to additionally also prove claims on the dependence of the solution on the initial point, you also need to allow for small variations $|x_0'-x_0|\le b'$ of this initial point in the fixed-point computations. Then you want 
$$
|x(t)-x_0|\le |x(t)-x_0'|+|x_0'-x_0|\le C|t-t_0|+b'\le Ca'+b'
\overset{\Large !}\le b
$$
giving a correspondingly smaller value of $a'$.

Comment: So is the smaller value of $a'$ simply $(b-b')/C$?

Comment: Yes. I think the text did not want to draw attention to these concrete expressions because these values are quite arbitrary, there is no deeper meaning in them.

Comment: Thanks! But if they are arbitrary, how it makes sure that the solution lies inside the cone $K_x$? I was trying to find a connection but not quite.

Comment: The geometric configuration has to be satisfied. You get for instance differences if you change the initial cylinder, if different norms are used etc.